# Font is a namespace but is used like a type error

Tags: c#, fonts

> I have the following error Font is a namespace but is used like a type error
> when running this code:

```
namespace Font
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fontFamily_MS_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sampleText.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif");  
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it's because it's due the namespace as the top is named Font.
But I'm not sure how to fix it?

It's my first-time programming in C# using Visual Studio, so I'm not really sure on how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Well, `Font` *is* a namespace.  That's indicated in the very first line of code shown.  Given that, what exactly are you expecting `new Font()` to do and why?

Comment: @MaciejLos, that's not true. Using a different name in the first place would have avoided it but changing the project name now won't change the default namespace automatically, never mind the namespace for existing types.

Comment: @MaciejLos, I just tested it in VS 2022 to confirm before posting and it didn't for me. I tested again and still see nothing. How did you do it? I clicked the project then clicked again in the Solution Explorer and typed in a new name. The second time I right-clicked and selected *Rename*.

Comment: @MaciejLos, that still won't affect existing types; only types you create after the change. It works in VB because there is no `Namespace` directive for types in the default namespace but C# types are generally within a `namespace` block and this one certainly is.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, again, you're right. :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your default namespace is `Font`, which indicates that you named your project "Font", which is a really bad name. Your project is not a font, so don't name it "Font". Use descriptive names for everything, including your projects, and you're less likely to have name clashes like this.

Now that that's already done, unless you want to create a new project, you can change the default namespace in the project properties and then change the namespace in all your code files. VS should prompt you to change them I think, so you can accept that and let VS do it for you. I'm not 100% sure about that though, because I use ReSharper and it might be just that doing it for me. Regardless, you can do a *Replace in Files* to find "namespace Font" and replace it with the new namespace name.

If you don't want to do that and leave all your current naming in place, you need to qualify the `Font` type:

```cs
sampleText.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif");
```

Answer (score -2):

You must use "using System.Drawing;"

Comment: That will not work. The current namespace takes precedence over any imported namespace.